# Add -D parameter to Tomcat's JVM

Tags: tomcat, jenkins

i have a rather simple question, but i was not able to the correct answer so for on my own.

We running an Jenkins server as a webapp on Tomcat and we need to locate the startup parameters that are passed to Tomcat's JVM. I need to add the following parameter:

```
-Dorg.apache.commons.logging.simplelog.log.IntegritySCM=debug
```

**Can you tell me were to find these parameters?**

Could it be: %PathToTomcatInstallationRoot%/conf/catalina.PROPERTIES

Or: Starting %PathToTomcatInstallationRoot%/bin/Tomcat7w.exe application -> Java/Startup?

I'm not sure, because editing this did not have any effect so far.

**EDIT:**

Tomcat is running as Windows service on an Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise (64-bit)

Comment: It depends on how you start the Tomcat server. Is it setup as a service, a regular application, an Eclipse plugin, ...? And what's the operating system?

Comment: Thanks for your fast respons. See edit above please :)

Answer (score 1):

Run the `tomcatXw.exe` (where X is the major version number of Tomcat you are running) program in Tomcat's `bin` directory to configure the parameters used for your Tomcat Windows Service. There are lots of things you can do in there including configure any `-D`-style system properties you want.

Comment: so my idea in [TomcatFolder]\bin\Tomcat7w was a good one i guess. But if i go to Java tab and fill in the -D property it has it has got no effect. Any idea why?

Comment: What exactly did you add? Did you restart the service?

Comment: I’ve started %TomcatInstallationFolder%/bin/Tomcat7w.exe application to gain access to all needed Tomcat properties.
 
I have switched over to the “Java” Tab  and added the –D option to the “Java Option” and restarted Tomcat -> no effect for the build. Log was the same...

Comment: Use `jconsole` or `jinfo` to find out what the system properties look like for that process. Are you in fact launching Tomcat from the Windows Service snap-in?

Comment: how to use jconsole or jinfo? The service is listed at the Windows Services and is started/stoped via the Tomcat Gui itselft (not directly windows sercvice snap-in)

Comment: [Google for jconsole](http://lmgtfy/?q=jsoncole) or [jinfo](http://lmgtfy/?q=jinfo).

Comment: I cannot see this java tab when looking at the properties of Tomcat7w.exe. I'm running it as a service on Windows 2008R2.

Comment: It's not the "properties of `Tomcat7w.exe`"... it's the property sheet shown when you actually *run* `tomcat72.exe`.